# commutative diagram having drawings as objects

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I need to draw a commutative diagram having drawings as objects, like in [this](http://poisson.phc.unipi.it/~tamburrino/unipi/tesi.pdf#page=35) link which is also shown below.

[image]

I have some problems:

1. xy-pic "slants" the objects;
2. "matrix" library in TiKZ is not happy to have other TiKZ commands in the matrices I wnat to draw.

What can I do?
This is a tentative answer to my problem:

```
\[
\xymatrix@C=2cm@M=3mm{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\filldraw[lightgray] (0,0) -- (2,0) -- (2,1) -- (0,1) -- cycle;
\draw (0,0) -- (2,0);
\draw (0,1) -- (2,1);
\end{tikzpicture} \ar@{->>}[r]
&
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[fill=lightgray] (0,0) ellipse (.5cm and .25cm);
\filldraw[lightgray] (-.5,0) -- (.5,0) -- (.5, .6) -- (-.5, .6) -- cycle;
\draw (-.5,0) -- (-.5, .6);
\draw (.5,0) -- (.5, .6);
\draw[fill=lightgray,yshift=.6cm] (0,0) ellipse (.5cm and .25cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
}\]
```

as you can see the arrow is "too low".

Comment: Sorry, I thought I linked it at the right page (27)... maybe the "#page=35" part can't be read by browser different from Chrome?

Comment: you can place nodes without `matrix` library.

Comment: I know, but I was wondering if there are some well-written solutions to this (quite natural if you handle geometric topology ;) ) problem...

Comment: You should be able to draw inside a TikZ matrix. See page 202 (introduction to matrices) in the manual.

Comment: Did I include the right image? Also matrix library is quite cooperative, what kind of difficulty did you have before?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [tikz-cd](http://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-cd). It is the `tikz` analog to `xy-matrix`, it easy to use, and it is reasonably flexible. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\pgfdeclareimage[interpolate=true]{image-name}{circle}

$$
\begin{tikzcd}
    \pgfuseimage{image-name} \rar[start anchor=real east] & \node[draw,circle]{A};
\end{tikzcd}
$$

\end{document}
```

Note that you need to modify the anchors of the arrows (where the arrows begin and end) since the anchors of the nodes in `tikz-cd` are shifted for technical reasons (cf. Sec. 3.3 in the package's manual). The circle on the left is a node as defined by `tikz-cd`, hence adjustment is necessary. The other is a normal node, so no adjustment is necessary.

Also, note that you can use `pgf` to include your drawings from separate files (since it seems you use several). This has the advantage that each image is included just once in the PDF file and it can be used many times without increasing the size of the file a lot.

Edit: Example

[image: Example]

Replace the polygons with fancier graphics, and you can get very nice diagrams with very simple code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes} % to draw polygons

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}
  \node[draw,regular polygon, regular polygon sides=5]{}; \rar{\varphi}
  \drar \arrow[bend right=50]{d} &
  \node[draw,circle]{}; \dlar[crossing over] \\
  \node[draw,regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6]{}; \arrow{r}[description]{\psi} &
  \node[draw,circle]{};
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

Also, I want to stress what I wrote in one comment, `tikz-cd` changes the arrows parameters (only in diagrams of course) for the arrows to look *exactly* as the arrows from the `amsmath` package. Very important...

Comment: If you have the inner pictures, you don't need tikz-cd anyway. You can just use `path-picture` option on a node. Also `tikz-cd` loads TikZ so there is no need to load `pgf`.

Comment: It seems that if you don't load `pgf` explicitely you cannot use the command `\pgfuseimage`, at least in my installation.

Comment: Also, for the case-use of the OP, `tikz-cd` seems as a good choice since it provides an easy-to-use front-end to pgf/tikz for example to add labels and descriptions to arrows, cross-overs, control the curvature of the arrows and so on... But perhaps one of the nicests things it is that it modifies the parameters of the default arrows to make them exactly like the arrows from the `amsmath` package. I will add a more complicated example to show what I mean.

Comment: @percusse Actually, I was mistaken. Apparently my problem with the undefined command appeared *because* of loading `pgf`... Thanks, I have corrected my answer.

Comment: No problem, wha I meant in my slightly cocky comment is that the real challenge is to make readily made nodes that have those curves inside them for frequent use (at least that's how I read the question) otherwise you can't change the line width, color etc. (if you ever want that). Otherwise you solution is the practical way to go.

Comment: Yeah, it seems that writing a package (perhaps using tikz) for drawing such nodes would be necessary to have a really convenient solution for handling such complicated nodes.